# Breaking Habitual Sin Through Understanding of Karma

Tags: karma, insight

Even though I am Catholic, I am discovering the Truth of the existence of karma through personal experience in my own spiritual journey.

There is a certain habitual sin that I am struggling with. After reading the Buddha's teaching, he said that when habitual sin repeats, it is because there is a pattern of karma that comes together under very specific logical conditions (conditions that can be numbered 1, 2, 3) to result in you making the choice to sin.

What strategies does the Buddha offer to:

1. Loosen this bad karma
2. Discover the logical conditions that cause this sin to repeat
3. Change the context so that the logical conditions causing this sin no longer arise?

Comment: Where did you read this? "*he (Buddha) said that when habitual sin repeats, it is because there is a pattern of karma that comes together under very specific logical conditions ... to result in you making the choice to sin.*"

Comment: @ruben2020 It came from this website: https://www.namchak.org/community/blog/karma-in-buddhism/ "First, if all the causes and conditions for something to occur come together and there is nothing opposing its arising, the effect is certain to occur. For example, if a barley seed (the cause) is planted, the conditions of moisture, warmth, sunlight, and nutrients  come together, and opposing conditions such as frozen ground, disease, and being trampled by animals,  don’t oppose it, a barley plant is certain to grow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Karma exists for every living being in the 31 Realms. It means results of the actions you've done in your past lives. There are Good Karma and Bad Karma which brings you favourable and unfavourable results in this life + the ones yet to come in the future.

So results coming from your old Karma can make you create new Karma today.

That's why you are in the loop of birth & death.

Sin is a bad action which accumulates Bad Karma which can go live in this life, the next or the one in the far future.

Now how exactly old Karma push you to create new Karma:

→ Let's say someone blame/accuse you for no logical reason. How do you react? If you blame him back with anger, you've created new Karma.

It doesn't matter how much you were right when they blamed you.
It doesn't matter how much you think the situation was unfair to you.
If you get anger, you've created new Karma.

Why did you have to be blamed with no fault:
→ Mostly because of a Bad Karma your past life performed. Situation may look unfair, but if you Zoom Out to see the whole picture, you were blamed for a fair reason: Because you created that result in a past life.

Similarly, habitual sins or bad actions you do all the time even if you're aware that's a bad action can have the same supporting environment from your past Karma.

In Buddhism, you can change the outcome of a Past Karma in a few ways.

1. Pratikarma — Doing new positive karma negating the outcome of a past karma
2. Upakrama — Strategically minimize/stop the impact of the outcome

Pratikarma is paying the debt of your past misdeeds and karma through,

1. Maitree Meditation
2. Donating food and other things to Buddha Temples & monks
3. Inspiring others to practice Buddhist way of life
4. Pin & Kusal Upload
5. Chanting Buddha Sutra, Pirith and Gatha

Upakrama means wearing Buddha Yantra, using medicine etc.

Pratikarma is the best way to loosen your bad karma as it doesn't just block them, but neutralize them according to the power generated by your Pratikarmas.

What is the logical condition that cause you to sin repeatedly?
→ Not knowing the bitter outcome and the depth your sin or action is going to bring you.
→ Not knowing it is Insatiable. Not according to your wish.
→ Not knowing it is meaningless. If something brings you pain sooner or later, it is meaningless.

When you do something with Raga (Lust), Dwesha (Anger), Moha (Delusion), you're creating karma. If it's a bad thing you did, then it's a sin. If it's a good thing you did, then it's a good deed.

For example, when you blame someone with anger. You're creating an outcome where you've to get blamed too. But when it comes back to you it won't be just One-time Blame. It'll be trillions of blames for you.

**HOW?**
→ 1 Thought is made up with a massive amount of Chittakshana. So the return must be that many times.
→ 1 Thought reaches 10,000 Lokha Dhatus containing a massive amount of 31 Realms polluting & corrupting the minds of other beings. So you've done a misdeed to "all the beings in the world". So the return comes back that many times.

When you realize the depth of your sin and the suffering you've to face from your Habitual Sin, you can control yourself not to do it. Depending on the depth of this understanding, you'll be able to fully stop the Habitual Sin.

Once you reach one of the 4 stages of awakening — Sowan, Sakrudagami, Anagami and Arihath — that control will become 2nd nature to you.

I'd say learn more Buddha Dharma, then start meditating with Arya Karmastana. It'll improve your life, but will also let you attain Nibbana one day.

Hope this answers your questions!

Comment: What does Theravada Buddhism have to say about self-love?

Comment: @Amatsuki What do you mean by self-love? Few examples?

Comment: Love that has its final cause back towards itself. Christianity sees it as the root of all evil. "[Love]...is not self-seeking" (1 Cor. 13:5)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to carefully & thoroughly read [MN 61](https://suttacentral.net/mn61/en/horner?reference=none&highlight=false) and [MN 19](https://suttacentral.net/mn19/en/horner?reference=none&highlight=false).

Comment: Thank you. This will hopefully lead to enlightenment.

Answer (score -2):

habits do repeat. that is the definition of habit. a pattern of doing; a habit(bhava).

sin is silly.  it means bad. it's flavored with societal taboo. an accepted formula for cause-effect. i prefer condition (society) and intuition. why push yourself into a corner? sin is an influx of karma, or [asrava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asrava). buddhism describes the causes as desire, desire for becoming, and ignorance.

the generally accepted view of karma is action, but according to Sadhguru Jaggi Vasudev, karma is created from being not in a union with the world, i.e., discordant, non-harmonious living. in unity no karma is generated.  so yes, karma is action, but it's more like unskillful action.  unskillful action results in karma.....that's the theory.

but the reality is different.  buddha speaks of the unsatisfactory.  ***sabbe saṅkhārā aniccā***.  this means mentality is undesirable. and so, without a me, there can be no karmic buildup. this is nirvana, a [jivanmuktha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jivanmukta). unfortunately, one has to burn up (experience) all the past karma first, e.g., buddha as an ascetic.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing Buddhist, Jain and Hindu teachings in one answer. Having to burn all past karma is Jain and was rejected by the Buddha.

Comment: Thank you for your truthful answer!

Comment: @ruben2020 yes, u r right.  on a side note, the rumor is that v. maudgalyayana experienced past karma after nirvana.